# Submit button to trigger thank you page

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

My actual test **[website](https://www.christianluneborg.com/indexdev.html)**

1.) Click on the hero head image on the top
2.) The dark gray box of the form slides in
3.) Do not fill in the form
4.) Click once on the submit button
5.) Then click on the hero head again
6.) The blue box of the Thank you page slides in

This shouldnt happen this way.

Before adding the PHP functionality of the form, I want to test the onClick submit button (not the hero head) to slide in the blue box Thank you page when form is filled in.

jQuery - I set two classes one for the hero head to slide in the form and one for the Thank you page.

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/magnix2k/chnaxwvz/53/) does not actually show the blue box instead it goes to 404 error page

```
 <script>
  $(".openNav").click(function() {
    $('.box').show();
    $('.box').toggleClass("slideUp");
  });

  $(".openNav2").click(function() {
    $('.box2').show();
    $('.box2').toggleClass("slideUp");
  });
  </script>
```

HTML -

```
<div class="box2 slideUp" style="display: none;">
    <div class="info">
      <div class="frm-details">
        <div class="frm-name">THANK YOU!</div>
        <div class="frm-header">I will get back to you ASAP!</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


**<!-- DARK GRAY BOX SLIDES IN -->**

<div class="box slideUp" style="display: none;">
    <div class="info">
      <div class="frm-details">
        <div class="frm-name">FILL OUT THE FORM</div>
        <div class="form-box">
          
          <form>

            <div class="frm-group">      
              <input type="text" required>
              <span class="frm-highlight"></span>
              <span class="frm-bar"></span>
              <label>Full Name</label>
            </div>
              
            <div class="frm-group">      
              <input type="text" required>
              <span class="frm-highlight"></span>
              <span class="frm-bar"></span>
              <label>Email</label>
            </div>

            <div class="frm-group">      
              <input type="text" required>
              <span class="frm-highlight"></span>
              <span class="frm-bar"></span>
              <label>Text Number</label>
            </div>

            <div class="frm-group">      
              <input type="text" required>
              <span class="frm-highlight"></span>
              <span class="frm-bar"></span>
              <label>Company Name</label>
            </div>

            <div class="frm-group">     
              <textarea type="text" rows="6" required></textarea> 
              <span class="frm-highlight"></span>
              <span class="frm-bar"></span>
              <label>Message</label>
            </div>
            <div class="" id=""><button class="btn-submit" class="openNav2">SEND</button> **<-- CLICK TO SLIDE THE THANK YOU BLUE BOX** 
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  **<!-- HERO HEAD TO CLICK -->**

  <div class="img-circle"><a href="javascript:;" class="openNav"><img src="imgs/img-christian.png"></a></div>
```

CSS -

```
  /* GRAY FORM BOX */
  .box {
  position: fixed;
  width: 288px;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #0b151b;
  z-index: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  top: 170px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
 }

  .box.slideUp {
  height: 0;
  }

 /* BLUE THANK YOU BOX */
 .box2 {
  position: fixed;
  width: 288px;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #0084ff;
  z-index: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  top: 170px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  }

 .box2.slideUp {
  height: 0;
  }
```

Comment: You should validate your submit before running the `openNav2`. Its the only way to know truly if you submit something and it's valid to show the blue window, rather than just running it on every click. Also, your `anchor` wrapping arround the button for `OpenNav2` is not included in your code. Its in live, but not here. This may give some mixed reactions

Comment: Ok, going to build the PHP for the form first and check if that blue thank you page will work. Thanks!

Comment: Do it in js and tie it in with a global var you set when submit